# What is the allowed operator in a global/ local theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, symmetry, gauge-theory

While I'm reading [Hong Liu's notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/resources/mit8_821s15_lec7/), it says:

> Now we have introduced two theories:
>
> (a)$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{g^2}Tr[\frac{1}{2}(\partial \Phi )^2+\frac{1}{4}\Phi^4]$$
>
> (b)$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{g^2_{YM}}[-\frac{1}{4}Tr F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-i\bar{\Psi}(\not{D}-m)\Psi]$$
>
> (a) is invariant under the global $U(N)$ transformation, and (b) is invariant under local $U(N)$ transformation.

What confused me is the description:

> On the other hand, consider allowed operators in the two theories. In (a), operators like $\Phi^a_b$ are allowed, although
> it is not invariant under global $U(N)$ symmetry. But in (b), allowed operators must be gauge invariant, so $\Phi^a_b$ is not allowed.

I remember that in electrodynamics the operator must be gauge invariant, but I don't know why in (a) can allow the operator which is not invariant under global $U(N)$ symmerty.

Furthermore, how do we decide on which operator should be invariant under what transformation? Are the operators invariant under gauge transformation because how the real world performs?